# Can i use ping command in the android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I encounter a very strange problem:
In my host pc,i use dhcp.
And my emulator,4.0.3 can log into the net via browswer.like:

[image]

But,when i use the adb shell to connect to this emulator and try to ping www.baidu.com,it loop there,like:

[image]

Any idea?thx

Answer (score 7):

It seems like Qemu user networking mode (default for android emulator) does not support ICMP protocol (ping). So you cannot ping a host in android emulator without changing network settings.

http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#User_Networking_.28SLIRP.29

If you just want to see if you can access a certain host, you can try to connect to a port you know it's open using netcat (nc). For example to check if you can access www.baidu.com, you can try connecting port 80 (HTTP)

`nc -v www.baidu.com 80`

You will see a message like this if connection is successful

`Connection to www.baidu.com 80 port [tcp/www] succeeded!`

If you really want to be able to use ping, you can follow the steps in this blog post. Sorry, instructions are for linux only. But it may give you an idea on how to do it in windows.

http://emulatorforandroid.blogspot.jp/2013/04/enabling-ping-and-icmp-on-android.html

Comment: This is a great idea, except netcat by default leaves the connection open for a very long time, longer than a minute and a half in my tests. Appending the "-w" flag with a timeout value will silently close the connection after [timeout] seconds.

Comment: Blogpost now available here https://gist.github.com/manojrege/9e491f902767898af1af1665c8c531db